# if condition between from time and to time vb.net

Tags: vb.net

i am trying to write a if condition in Vb.net where i would like to call a SQL procedure if the IF condition is satisfied.But the below condition which I am using is not working . Please let me know when i am wrong.

```
  Dim dt As DateTime, hh As Integer, mm As Integer
        dt = DateTime.Now
        hh = dt.Hour
        mm = dt.Minute
     If  ((hh > 00 or mm > 30) and (hh <= 9 or mm < 30 )) Then 

     End if
```

Need help if the if condition is correct .

Comment: Well, what is the logic at all? For instance, this doesnt make any sense at all: `hh > 00 or mm > 30`. Also note that you should use `AndAlso` and `OrElse` instead of `And` and `Or`.

Comment: Please don't expect us to try to work out what you want to from code that doesn't do it.  ALWAYS provide a FULL and CLEAR explanation of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the condition is that the current time is between 0:30 and 9:30.

```
Dim now = DateTime.Now
Dim startTime = DateTime.Today.AddMinutes(30)
Dim endTime = DateTime.Today.AddHours(9).AddMinutes(30)

If now > startTime AndAlso now < endTime Then

End If
```

Note that you should use `AndAlso` and `OrElse` instead of `And` and `Or`